# Apply patchset and encounter conflicts

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

I am working on kernel patchset rather than git stuffs. eg: this patch:[1](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/dri-devel/cover/20210114221709.2261452-1-lyude@redhat.com/)

I download this series of patch and run follow command to patch to kernel-next.

```
      "patch -p1 < ../xxx.patch".
```

I get some rej files after apply patch.

Does this mean I have to cheery-pick other patch or I have to need fix those reject file one by one.

[one of reject file look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB0iI.png)

thanks!!

Comment: Try `git am -3`, if your kernel has `.git` dir. But yeah, you'll have to track and apply all patch dependencies first, and that could be a major pain. Thus it's recommended to use git when you work with Linux. When you have `.git`, you can start thinking in term of patches, find a base commit for the patch you want to apply and your kernel, and then look for all dependencies (in git tree or on mailing list, etc). Anyway it's not easy to just apply a patch, when you don't know exact tag or SHA on top of which you should apply it. Usually you have to apply feature branches as dependencies first.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`patch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) man page:

> If patch cannot find a place to install that hunk of the patch, it
> puts the hunk out to a reject file, which normally is the name of the
> output file plus a .rej suffix, or # if .rej would generate a file
> name that is too long (if even appending the single character # makes
> the file name too long, then # replaces the file name's last
> character).
>
> The rejected hunk comes out in unified or context diff format. If the
> input was a normal diff, many of the contexts are simply null.  The
> line numbers on the hunks in the reject file may be different than in
> the patch file: they reflect the approximate location patch thinks the
> failed hunks belong in the new file rather than the old one.

So essentially your patches failed to apply cleanly. Fix the lines shown in the `.rej` files in the **original file** that it failed for.

```
echo "this is test file" > test.txt

echo "this is testy file" > testy.txt

echo "this is test  file" > test1.txt #note the extra space

diff test.txt testy.txt > diff.patch

cat diff.patch
1c1
< this is test file
---
> this is testy file

patch -p1 test1.txt diff.patch #trying to patch test1.txt with the diff
patching file test1.txt
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file test1.txt.rej

cat test1.txt.rej
***************
*** 1
- this is test file
--- 1 -----
+ this is testy file
```

So, in this (dumb example) case, the `test1.txt.rej` indicates that `test1.txt` needs to be fixed. You need to manually merge the changes from `drm_dp_helper.c.rej` file to the file that the `patch` program failed to apply the changes to i.e. `drm_dp_helper.c`, which guessing from the failed hunk in the patch is essentially deleting a bunch of arrays etc. I'm guessing your version of `drm_dp_helper.c` isn't at the same change version with the original patch author's base file and might have had some changes which are leading to the patch application failure.